# How to open dialog and wait for user confirmation before jumping to next element in array?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Tried different ways like async/await, callbacks, but not able to open a dialog box for each element, can someone please help me with basic implementation?

here is the code I am trying
https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dialogopenonebyone?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask].If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor HERE

Comment: Your stackblitz does not even run

Comment: Can u please check now, It is working..

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of your question, you want to open a dialog box for each element in the array, what you can do is create a dialog box element and make it visible using the property display

```
<h5>Basic</h5>
<ul *ngFor="let activity of duplicateList;let i=index;">
  <li>{{activity.label}} -- {{activity.present}}
  </li>
  <p-dialog id="id">
    <p-header>
      {{activity.label}}
    </p-header>

    <p-footer>
      <button type="button" pButton icon="pi pi-check" (click)="openDialog(activity)" label="Yes"></button>
      <button type="button" pButton icon="pi pi-close" (click)="closeDialog()" label="No" class="ui-button-secondary"></button>
    </p-footer>
  </p-dialog>
</ul>

<div *ngIf="display" class="dialog-box">
  {{content}}
</div>
```

in the app.component.ts file you can add the openDialog and closeDialog methods as below

```
  openDialog(activity: any){
      this.display = true;
      this.content = activity
  }
  closeDialog(){
    this.display = false;
  }
```

Comment: I am trying to open dialog box for array elemnet and let user update the label and on confirmation call next array element.but angular is not calling dialog box for each element instead it calls only last elemnt.